# No route matches [POST] "/line_items/1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a cart for a user. It is based on the flanger app from web crunch, the association is:

```
cart has many line items
item has many line items 
line item belongs to item
line item belongs to cart
```

in model Cart, I created add_item method:

```
def add_item(item)
    current_item = line_items.find_by(item_id: item.id)
    if current_item
        current_item.increment(:quantity)
    else
        current_item = line_items.build(item_id: item.id)
    end
    current_item
 end
```

for the line_items controller , It was generated by "rails g scaffold" command

in line_items_controller.rb:

```
before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]    
def index
  @line_items = LineItem.all
end

def show
end

def new
  @line_item = LineItem.new
end

def create
item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
@line_item = @cart.add_item(item)

respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Item added' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

private

def set_line_item
  @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
end

def line_item_params
  params.require(:line_item).permit(:item_id)
end
```

For the current_cart module:

```
def set_cart
  @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  @cart = Cart.create
  session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
end
```

in Item/show.html.erb, I create a button to add the current item to cart:

```
<%= button_to "Add to cart" ,line_item_path(item_id: @item),class:'btn btn-success'%>
```

in routes.rb:

```
resources :line_items
resources :carts
resources :items
```

So the error appeared whenever I click on the button "Add to Cart".
I'm looking for solutions to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you post your routes file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line_item_path(item_id: @item)` is generating the url `/line_items/1`, which is actually trying to perform a POST to following route:

```
line_item_path GET  /line_items/1     line_items#show
```

Changing your button to the following should do the trick:

```
<%= button_to "Add to cart", line_items_path(item_id: @item) %>
```

This will post to the `line_items_path` (CREATE) with `item_id` in the params.

Comment: oh, It informs me of a new error: 
    uninitialized constant ApplicationControllerude.
    Rails.root: /home/default/shopping